# How to use fetch API to get an Array back?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have an API which will return an array to me.
I tried to use fetch API to get the array back.
I know that if I use fetch to acquire some data, the real body in the response is ReadableStream.
I usually to deal with it by `response.json()` in `then` function if data is json.
What I don't know is how to deal with array data?

Comment: Going to need to see what your API represents an Array as, and how you are currently attempting to fetch the data, using the `.json()` method would properly format and return an array value

Comment: What's "array data" if not JSON? CSV?

Comment: *confused* What specifically is the API sending back? Not JSON?

Comment: Won't you just need to parse the JSON?

Comment: @NatuMyers the `.json()` function would do that

Comment: You can also use `.text()` and parse anything yourself, in any format that you find a parser for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your API is not returning a JSON array `[1,2,3]` then you can use the [`.text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) function to get the raw value:

```
fetch('/api/text').then(function(response) {
  return response.text()
}).then(function (text) {
  // parse the text here how you want, for csv:
  // return text.split(',')
})
```

Otherwise you can simply just use the [`.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method to get the array value.

The [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) that you mention is to read a binary buffer, it can be useful for fetching songs or etc... If your API is returning this, I would check out the link to see what you can do. You will most likely be required to decode the buffer and how that is done is completely dependent on how your API is encoding it and I cannot answer that without more detail regarding your API response.

Comment: Just realized that .split(',') turns the text into array :)